# How to undo `get_something` on channel delete

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

So i have this script, when a channel is created, it adds on in `My_channels` with the `get_My_channels` on `on_channel_create`, but i don't know how to remove it from `My_channels` when a channel with that name is deleted using `on_channel_delete` so when a message get's sent to that channel, it won't give me an error that it's an unavailable channel

```
#When channel is created it works
My_channels=[]
@client.event
async def on_channel_create(GlobalChat):
    await get_My_channels() #< That line adds the created channel to My_channels if the channel has the name 'GlobalChat'
```

## But now when channel is deleted is where the error comes

```
@client.event
async def on_channel_delete(GlobalChat):
    await """This is the part it should remove it from My_channels()"""
```

Comment: What is `My_channels`?  Is it a list?

Comment: Yes `My_channels=[]`